# Обернуть каждое значение в кавычки SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Выполняю обычный 
`select name from table`
в postgresql и получаю столбец строковых значений в виде:

```
ааа
ббб
ггг
```

Можно ли как-то изменить запрос, чтобы каждое значение в столбце выводилось обернутым в кавычки (желательно одинарные), вот так:

```
'aaa'
'ббб'
'ггг'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо через символ конкатенации `||` добавить "оборачивание" в `'`

```
select '''' || name || '''' as name from table
```